# How to get info if there any new tab or browser is opened while application is running?

Tags: asp.net

How to get info if there any new tab or browser is opened while application is running?
For online examination tool i want to implement a feature that while giving test if user open a new tab or a new browser than it would notify me. 
**How can i achieve this task in .dot?**

Comment: you mean a new tab and browse to your site, or in general look for answers anywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your exam application is going to be a ASP.Net website/web application, then **you can't** detect how many tabs/browsers instance are open. You can look into [HTML5 Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode) for a wayout, but I don't think all the browser has support for it.